# Scrollview is not working in pageradapter class for viewpager android

Tags: android-viewpager, android-scrollview, vertical-scrolling

Im creating one sample application in that application Im using viewpager in activity and scrollview in pageradapter, issue is viewpager working fine but scrollview is sticky im not able to scroll up and down, i dont know were i made mistake can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

```
 public class JokeDetailPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


private int ConvertPixelsToDp(float pixelValue) {
    int ConvertPixelsToDpInteger = (int) ((pixelValue) / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    return ConvertPixelsToDpInteger;
}

// init LayoutInflater variable
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

// init array of the color
private int[] colors = new int[]{0xffffd200, 0xff37beb7, 0xff00ccff, 0xff8585c1, 0xfff2a03c, 0xff2a80b9, 0xfff15972,
        0xffe9776c, 0xff9dcc96, 0xff76c069};

// define hex color to an integer
int defaultcolor = 0xff666666;

// init Context variable
Context context;

public static String image_path;

public static Uri bmpUri = null;
public static File jokedetailfile;

// init String variable
String joke_id, user_id, user_type_id, desc, userLikeString, userDislikeString, share_textjoke, jokeingid, Token, option;

// init static String variable
   public static String status, senddislikeCount, sendlikeCount;


// init SharedPreferences variable
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private SharedPreferences pref;

// init Check Internet variable
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
ConnectionDetector cd;

// init LayoutInflater variable
//    LinearLayout mLinearListView;

// init Integer variable
int new_color, coloring, color, width;

// init ArrayList variable
public JokeDetailPageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> UserName, ArrayList<String> JokeLike
        , ArrayList<String> Jok_id, ArrayList<String> Jok_desc, ArrayList<String> Jok_img
        , ArrayList<String> Jok_is_active, ArrayList<String> Jok_nsfw
        , ArrayList<String> Jok_total_comments, ArrayList<String> Jok_total_flags
        , ArrayList<String> Jok_total_shares, ArrayList<String> Jok_created_on
        , ArrayList<String> Jok_modified_on, ArrayList<String> Jok_userimg
        , ArrayList<String> LikeCount, ArrayList<String> DislikeCount
        , ArrayList<String> JokePopular, ArrayList<String> languageName
        , ArrayList<String> textJoke, ArrayList<String> Type_of_jokes) {
    this.context = context;
    HomeListAdapter.userName = UserName;
    HomeListAdapter.jokeLike = JokeLike;
    HomeListAdapter.jok_id = Jok_id;
    HomeListAdapter.jok_desc = Jok_desc;
    HomeListAdapter.jok_img = Jok_img;
    HomeListAdapter.jok_is_active = Jok_is_active;
    HomeListAdapter.jok_nsfw = Jok_nsfw;
    HomeListAdapter.jok_total_comments = Jok_total_comments;
    HomeListAdapter.jok_total_flags = Jok_total_flags;
    HomeListAdapter.jok_total_shares = Jok_total_shares;
    HomeListAdapter.jok_created_on = Jok_created_on;
    HomeListAdapter.jok_modified_on = Jok_modified_on;
    HomeListAdapter.jok_userimg = Jok_userimg;
    HomeListAdapter.likeCount = LikeCount;
    HomeListAdapter.dislikeCount = DislikeCount;
    HomeListAdapter.popularJoke = JokePopular;
    HomeListAdapter.languagename = languageName;
    HomeListAdapter.textjoke = textJoke;
    HomeListAdapter.type_of_jokes = Type_of_jokes;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return HomeListAdapter.userName.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    final Holder holder = new Holder();

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.joke_detail_adapter, container, false);

    // initialization check internet variable
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);

    // initialization sharedPreferences variable - get userId, userType, Token
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    editor = pref.edit();
    user_id = pref.getString("userId", null); // getting String
    user_type_id = pref.getString("typeId", null);
    Token = pref.getString("Token", null);

    // initialization UI variable
    holder.UserNameTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_jokes_username); // set textView to xml id
    holder.up = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_up);
    holder.down = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_down);
    holder.user_profile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_jokes_user_profile);
    holder.jokeId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_jokesId);
    holder.description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_jokes_description);
    holder.smiles = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_jokes_smiles);
    holder.frowns = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_jokes_frowns);
    holder.comments = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_jokes_comments);
    holder.share = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_jokes_share);
    holder.language = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_lang);
    holder.list_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_jokes_list_image);
    holder.extend = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_extend);
    holder.share_icon = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_share_icon);
    holder.flag_icon = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_flag_icon);
    holder.jokes_list_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_jokes_list_text);
    holder.markPopular = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_mark_popular);
    holder.time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_time);
    holder.description_block = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_description_block);
    holder.title_bar = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_title_bar);
    holder.pager_comment_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_comment_icon);
    holder.pager_upvote = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_upvote);
    holder.pager_downvote = (LinearLayout)        itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_downvote);
      //mLinearListView = (LinearLayout)          itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_commentlist);
   // mLinearListView.removeAllViews();
    holder.coverImagePic = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coverImagePic);
    holder.pager_detail_scroll = (ScrollView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager_detail_scroll);

    holder.UserNameTxt.setText(HomeListAdapter.userName.get(position)); // set user name text
    holder.smiles.setText(HomeListAdapter.likeCount.get(position)); // set like count text
    holder.frowns.setText(HomeListAdapter.dislikeCount.get(position)); // set disLike count text
    holder.comments.setText(HomeListAdapter.jok_total_comments.get(position)); // set comment count text
    holder.share.setText(HomeListAdapter.jok_total_shares.get(position)); // set share count text
    holder.description.setText(HomeListAdapter.jok_desc.get(position)); // set desc text
    holder.pager_downvote.setBackgroundColor(defaultcolor);
    holder.pager_upvote.setBackgroundColor(defaultcolor);

    new_color = colors[coloring];
    color = position % colors.length;
    itemView.setBackgroundColor(colors[color]);
    holder.title_bar.setBackgroundColor(colors[color]);
    holder.share_icon.setBackgroundColor(colors[color]);

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    // display desc when there is no null value
    if ((HomeListAdapter.jok_desc.get(position)).equals("")) {
        holder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.description_block.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        String decs = HomeListAdapter.jok_desc.get(position);
        decs = decs.replace("</p>","");
        decs = decs.replace("<p dir=\"ltr\">","");
        holder.description.setText(Html.fromHtml(decs));
    }

    // display Not Mentioned when lang have null value
    if (HomeListAdapter.languagename.get(position).equals("")) {
        holder.language.setText(R.string.notMentioned);
    } else {
        holder.language.setText(HomeListAdapter.languagename.get(position));
    }

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat1.parse(HomeListAdapter.jok_created_on.get(position));
        long times = parsedDate.getTime();
        new Timestamp(times);
        String result = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(times, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5 * 60 * 1000, 0);

        holder.time.setText(result);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.d(String.valueOf(R.string.errorreport), e.getMessage());
    }

    if (HomeListAdapter.jok_userimg.get(position).equals("")) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.male).placeholder(R.drawable.male).into(holder.user_profile);
    } else {
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(HomeListAdapter.jok_userimg.get(position)).transform(new RoundedTransformation(100, 0)).placeholder(R.drawable.male)
                .error(R.drawable.male).fit().into(holder.user_profile);
    }

    if (HomeListAdapter.type_of_jokes.get(position).equals("2")) {
        holder.list_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.jokes_list_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.jokes_list_text.setText(Html.fromHtml(HomeListAdapter.textjoke.get(position)));
    } else if (HomeListAdapter.type_of_jokes.get(position).equals("1")) {

        width = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        DisplayMetrics display = this.context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int widthInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(display.widthPixels);



        try {
            Glide.with(context).
                    load(Global_Url.image_url + HomeListAdapter.jok_img.get(position) + "?dim=" + String.valueOf(widthInDp))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_loading)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                    .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
                    .crossFade()
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            holder.share_icon.setSelected(true);
                            holder.share_icon.setEnabled(true);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable glideDrawable, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                            int width = glideDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                            int height = glideDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
                            holder.list_image.setImageDrawable(glideDrawable);
                        }
                    });
        }catch (Exception e){

        }


    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}

public class Holder {
    TextView UserNameTxt, jokeId, description, smiles, frowns, comments, share, jokes_list_text, language, time;  //Initialize TextView variable
    ImageView up, down, user_profile, list_image, pager_comment_icon;  //Initialize ImageView variable
    RelativeLayout extend;  //Initialize RelativeLayout variable
    LinearLayout share_icon, flag_icon, title_bar, set_share, description_block, pager_downvote, pager_upvote;  //Initialize LinearLayout variable
    CheckBox markPopular;  //Initialize CheckBox variable
    RelativeLayout coverImagePic;
    ScrollView pager_detail_scroll;
}
```

}

Xml.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager_card"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/pager_detail_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/pager_description_block"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pager_jokes_description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/coverImagePic"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/pager_jokes_list_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/image_loading"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pager_jokes_list_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.04"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```